# No supported card terminal found ARC1281U nfc card reader

Tags: java, android, nfc, hce

I'm trying to do Host card based emulation,[HCE](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fguide%2Ftopics%2Fconnectivity%2Fnfc%2Fhce.html&ei=j7yuVNOjOo-zuAT09oDoBQ&usg=AFQjCNHKCL7h7xqSdizIVPMpukW7l7267A&sig2=UjrJAxN_X0KirDDoZlrWmQ&bvm=bv.83339334,d.c2E) using this [example](http://blog.opendatalab.de/hack/2013/11/07/android-host-card-emulation-with-acr122/) for ACR 1281U Nfc card 
reader.

The tutorial Suggest to use [nfctools](https://github.com/grundid/nfctools-examples/releases) to read logs when connected to the reader b using the  command

```
java -cp "C:\DATA\setups\ACR1281U-C1 SDK v1.0\nfctools-examples.jar" org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo
```

But the error I get is on my windows 7 system

```
C:\DATA\setups\ACR1281U-C1 SDK v1.0\nfctools-examples\org\nfctools\examples\hce>
java -cp "C:\DATA\setups\ACR1281U-C1 SDK v1.0\nfctools-examples.jar" org.nfctool
s.examples.hce.HceDemo
Jan 08, 2015 12:17:29 AM org.nfctools.scio.TerminalHandler getAvailableTerminal
INFO: Checking terminal: ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader ICC 0
Jan 08, 2015 12:17:29 AM org.nfctools.scio.TerminalHandler getAvailableTerminal
INFO: Checking terminal: ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader PICC 0
Jan 08, 2015 12:17:29 AM org.nfctools.scio.TerminalHandler getAvailableTerminal
INFO: Checking terminal: ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader SAM 0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No supported card
 terminal found. Available Terminals  [ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader ICC 0] [ACS AC
R1281 1S Dual Reader PICC 0] [ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader SAM 0]
        at org.nfctools.scio.TerminalHandler.getAvailableTerminal(TerminalHandle
r.java:59)
        at org.nfctools.examples.TerminalUtils.getAvailableTerminal(TerminalUtil
s.java:34)
        at org.nfctools.examples.TerminalUtils.getAvailableTerminal(TerminalUtil
s.java:26)
        at org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo.run(HceDemo.java:10)
        at org.nfctools.examples.hce.HceDemo.main(HceDemo.java:16)
```

In one of the comments on blog some one mentions " Do you have pcsc installed? Java can only access the reader using a smartcard interface."

- Please suggest what is pcsc  and I how can I make this work ?
- How can I find out what AID should I register in my project which coresponds to my reader?

There are hardly any resources on HCE and I'm not able to find any solution to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message that you receive means that the nfctools library does not recognize any of the 3 interfaces of your smartcard reader

- ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader ICC 0
- ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader PICC 0
- ACS ACR1281 1S Dual Reader SAM 0

as a supported interface.